# Burn Bootloader to Chinese Arduino 2560 with AVR ISP programmer

Tags: bootloader, isp, clones, atmega2560

I got my hands on one of these [ISP programmer for Atmel AVR microcontroller in USB stick design](http://shop.myavr.com/index.php?sp=article.sp.php&artID=200006):

[image: mySmartUSB light]

Then I selected Progammer > AVR ISP and clicked on Burn Bootloader but it says

`stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`.

Has anybody any experience doing this and if so, could they point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**
I've also added the following to programmers.txt

```
mySmartUSB.name=mySmartUSB
mySmartUSB.protocol=stk500v2
mySmartUSB.communication=serial
mySmartUSB.program.tool=avrdude
mySmartUSB.program.extra_params=-P{serial.port}
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Majenko windows 8.1 Drivers seem to be fine and this device works with Atmel Studio

Comment: Did you select the right com port for the programmer?

Comment: @Delta_G sigh, I was had the board port instead of the programmer's port. Can you write it as an answer so I can mark correct and award the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is common and usually means you either have the wrong board selected or the wrong port.  Check the tools menu. Be sure you have the port for the programmer and not the port for the board if the board is also connected.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use another Arduino to burn bootloader on your Arduino 2560? Check [this(click here)](https://github.com/bigyanchapagain/Use-Arduino-as-ISP) tutorial on my Github page. Maybe this will help.